# What is this plant?

Tags: identification

What is this plant that started growing near an eggplant? 
I was removing weeds and noticed this sturdy plant. 
Its leaves have a little of a spiky fluffy texture.

[image: Sturdy plant]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like a potato plant.

It's possible this is potato from last year, or that compost not completely ready was used to prepare the soil.

Comment: I think so, I used soil from a field and it had bits of potatoes.
I tried to remove them when repotting and I may have left some.

Comment: It is a potato good call J. Chomel!